# Onclick event to addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

Check this code:

```
<script>
var next = document.getElementById("next");
var prev = document.getElementById("prev");

next.addEventListener("click",next(),false);
prev.addEventListener("click",prev(),false);

function next(e) {
e.preventDefault();
prev.style.display = "block";
next.style.display = "none";
}
function prev(e) {
e.preventDefault();
prev.style.display = "none";
next.style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<div id="nav">
<a href="javascript:void;" id="prev">&lsaquo;&lsaquo;&lsaquo;</a>
<a href="javascript:void;" id="next">&rsaquo;&rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

I don't know why this is not working. I'm loading script just before `<body>` tag. Please help.

It gives me error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'next' of object [object Object] is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the parenthesis to the functions, the functions are called immediately and the result, in this case undefined, is returned to addEventListener.

You want to reference the functions, not call them

```
next.addEventListener("click", next, false);
prev.addEventListener("click", prev, false);
```

The next error is that you're using the same names for the variables and functions, so when you say `next.style` it's now the function, not the element, as the function name overwrites the variable

```
var next_elem = document.getElementById("next");
var prev_elem = document.getElementById("prev");

next_elem.addEventListener("click", next_fn, false);
prev_elem.addEventListener("click", prev_fn, false);

function next_fn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    prev_elem.style.display = "block";
    next_elem.style.display = "none";
}

function prev_fn(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    prev_elem.style.display = "none";
    next_elem.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Okay. That fixed it. But Now when I click my a links, it gives me error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: Wow I totally missed that same function and variable names. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the function names. By specifying `()` along with the function name, they are called.

Change it to:

```
next.addEventListener("click",next,false);
prev.addEventListener("click",prev,false);
```